# Crescendo as text in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to implement the crescendo as text. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef1\treble
    \parindent0mm
    \nostartrule
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \startpiece 
    %1er compás - 1ra línea
    \NOtes\isluru0j\hl{j}\hl{l}\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \NOtes\hl{k}\tslur0n\hl{n}\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \NOtes\isluru0q\hl{q}\ql{l}\tslur0m\ql{m}\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \NOtes\zcn{M}{\hspace*{-0.15cm}\bf \f}\hl{n}\hp\en\bar
    %\5to compás
    \NOtes\zcn{M}{\hspace*{-0.15cm}\bf \p}\isluru0k\hl{k}\hl{n}\en\bar
    %6to compás
    \NOtes\hl{m}\curve {4}33\tslur0l\hl l\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.21cm} \cbreath}}\en
    \endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The current output is:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow (note that is needed the crescendo as text symbol):
[image: desired]

Comment: I would just insert it as a song: cres_-cen_-do__, but, actually, this, again is copying a for a musician ugly presentation. Normally it would be a \zcharnote c{\it crescendo} at the beginning, and everybody has to understand that it has to continu until the forte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef1\treble
    \parindent0mm
    \nostartrule
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \startpiece 
    %1er compás - 1ra línea
    \NOtes\zcharnote{-8}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[] at (0,0) {\hspace*{-0.4cm} \A\textbf{cres}};
        \draw[very thick, dashed, line width=0.3mm] (0.38,0) -- (1.37,0);
        \node[] at (1.61,0) {\hspace*{0.024cm} \A\textbf{cen}}; 
        \draw[very thick, dashed, line width=0.3mm] (2.0,0) -- (3.26,0);
        \node[] at (3.45,0) {\hspace*{0.006cm} \A\textbf{do}};  
        \draw[very thick, dashed, line width=0.3mm] (3.8,0) -- (5.36,0);
     \end{tikzpicture}}\isluru0j\hl{j}\hl{l}\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \NOtes\hl{k}\tslur0n\hl{n}\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \NOtes\isluru0q\hl{q}\ql{l}\tslur0m\ql{m}\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \NOtes\zcn{M}{\hspace*{-0.15cm}\bf \f}\hl{n}\hp\en\bar
    %\5to compás
    \NOtes\zcn{M}{\hspace*{-0.15cm}\bf \p}\isluru0k\hl{k}\hl{n}\en\bar
    %6to compás
    \NOtes\hl{m}\curve {4}33\tslur0l\hl l\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.21cm} \cbreath}}\en
    \endpiece
\end{music}    
\end{document}
```

[image: solved]